# Подскажите библиотеки для рисования (android)

Tags: java, android, графика, библиотеки

Мне нужна графическая библиотека, в которой можно разместить картинку и нарисовать линию, потому что встроенных адекватных библиотек я не нашёл.

Comment: *Библиотеки для Android Studio* нещадно минусую. Дешифровка для тех кто в танке: Android Studio - средство разработки, но не платформа/ось

Comment: не совсем понимаю ваше недовольство. Очевино, что разработчик начинающий.

Answer (score 0):

Странно, что вы не слышала о Canvas. По-моему это первое что приходит в голову при слове "нарисовать". https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas

**Дополнение:**

Есть отличный сайт (android arsenal) с различными либами, вот одна из простеньких канвас-либ, которую можно использовть для статического рисования: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1177 . Вряд ли вы найдете что-то более продвинутое, потому как canvas реализации у всех свои.